# How to serve a zip file download in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a zip file stored in the Django project directory. How can I serve it to users for downloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can serve any type of file using [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects), like so:

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

def zip_file_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(open('/path/to/your/zipfile.zip', 'rb'), content_type='application/zip')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=any_name_you_like.zip'
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to serve it as a static file. You can find the steps to set up serving of static files here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

Be aware that serving static files in production (not using django's built in server) requires a few extra steps which are mentioned in the #Deployment section